# Azure AD B2C - how to add custom attribute programmatically (extension property)

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

In order to have some extra data for my Azure AD B2C Users I want to create a new custom attribute for a User object (or extension property, which is I suppose the same thing). So I found this **[documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_extensionproperties)**. Is this a correct way of adding a custom attribute for a User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of adding attributes is through the 'portal.azure.com' administration portal.

You will also need to create a user through a policy before those attributes actually become available for all users.

The other thing to consider is that the extension name will be different in each environment, so you will need some custom logic to parse the users JSON that you get from the GraphApi, and check to be sure that the attribute ends with the name you gave that attribute.

Example:

```
//Java, sorry
private YourCustomGraphApiUser populateCustomProperty(JsonNode jsonUser) throws JsonProcessingException{

    YourCustomGraphApiUser azureUser = mapper.treeToValue(jsonUser, YourCustomGraphApiUser.class);
    String[] customAttributeNames = new String()["one","two"]; //Replace this with some values from some injected properties
    for(String attributeName : customAttributeNames){
        JsonNode customAttribute = jsonUser.get(attributeName);
        if(customAttribute != null){
            azureUser.set(attributeName, customAttribute.asText());//Assuming custom attributes are stored in a map-like structure in YourCustomGraphApiUser. 
        }
        else{                           
            throw new NotFoundException("Error getting the name for custom attribute "+attributeName, e);
            // OR you could ignore and just log an error. Whatever.
        }           
    }
    return azureUser;
}
```

Comment: Why can't I add custom attribute programmatically? I have a library which defines MyOwnUser, and for that user I need custom attributes. Why would I add those in the portal every time for different directories?

Comment: @alvipeo That is an excellent question! I have asked it many times myself. It's equally frustrating that I had to manually create an account with those attribute values before they would become available. If I were dead set on programmatic creation, I might look more into the B2C module for the azure powershell; I have never done it, but maybe you could create a script that would setup each environment. I have not worked with custom policies yet either, but I understand them to be more configurable (xml and stuff), although it takes more initial effort.

Comment: I just made a class creating extension properties in code. Need to finish with setting/reading its value from a User

Comment: Are you able to share the code you made for that? Also, which api version are you using?

Also, if you want to see what I did for updating a user and getting custom attributes, look here: https://github.com/Xitikit/xitikit-blue/blob/master/blue-kit/graph-api/src/main/java/org/xitikit/blue/graphapi/AzureGraphApiClient.java

It's based off of what I am using in production, but this version is still in progress. I had to change some things for licensing and legal reasons so everyone could use it.

Comment: I've got the whole lib with a bunch of tests now. Almost there. Will share some when it's all green.

Answer (score 1):

You create extensionProperty on the desired Application object using Graph API.

Sample JSON request:

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/applications/269fc2f7-6420-4ea4-be90-9e1f93a87a64/extensionProperties?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi...r6Xh5KVA
Content-Type: application/json
Host: graph.windows.net
Content-Length: 104
{
"name": "skypeId",
"dataType": "String",
"targetObjects": [
    "User"
]

}
```

If the operation was successful, it will return an HTTP 201 Created status code along with the fully-qualified extension property name, which can be used for writing values to the target type.
Reference: [azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions)